# c# XML Serialisation

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I've got this XML;

```
<ChartXml>
   <Category type="xAxis">
      <Value>Mon</Value>
      <Value>Tue</Value>
      <Value>Wed</Value>
      <Value>Thurs</Value>
      <Value>Friday</Value>
   </Category>
</ChartXml>
```

And this class structure;

```
[XmlRoot("ChartXml")]
public class ChartXml
{
    [XmlElement("Category")]
    public Category Category;            
}

public class Category
{        
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type;        
    [XmlArray("Value")]
    public List<string> Values;
}
```

Now when I try to serialise the XML to a ChartXml object, I get object containing the Category with the type attribute set correctly, but i dont get my list of strings.

I'm guessing its something wrong with the way i've set up my classes.

Thanks,
james.

Comment: The best way to identify this kind of problems is to actually reverse your serialization logic. Create the object with the data that matches the data you have in your XML. Then try to serialize it so that the output is the same as the data you would like to deserialize.

This way, you can actually 'see' the effect of the available attributes that you can apply on the properties.

If it serializes the same, you can also deserialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[XmlElement("Value")]` instead of `[XmlArray("Value")]`, e.g.:

```
[XmlRoot("ChartXml")]
public class ChartXml
{
    [XmlElement("Category")]
    public Category Category;
}

public class Category
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type;

    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public List<string> Values;
}
```

Serialization:

```
var obj = new ChartXml { Category = new Category { Type = "t", Values = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" } } };
var ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

using (var tw=new StringWriter())
{
    ser.Serialize(tw, obj);

    Console.WriteLine(tw.ToString());
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ChartXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http:
//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Category type="t">
    <Value>a</Value>
    <Value>b</Value>
    <Value>c</Value>
  </Category>
</ChartXml>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great. I was thinking as it was a list i wanted i needed to tell it it was an array, obviously not. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlElement("Value")] instead of [XmlArray("Value")]